# How I can create WTForms field subclasses?

Tags: python, inheritance, wtforms

I am trying to create subclasses from the default field classes of wtforms.

```
class MyForm(Form):
    fieldName = MyField('field name')
```

and the MyField is imported from another file

```
class MyField(TextField):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

but there are some errors when I create a MyForm originated here:

```
In [5]: f = MyForm()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
path/<ipython-input-5-decc3699f7c4> in <module>()
----> 1 f = RegistrationForm()

path/wtforms/form.pyc in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    176             fields.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1].creation_counter, x[0]))
    177             cls._unbound_fields = fields
--> 178         return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    179 
    180     def __setattr__(cls, name, value):

path/wtforms/form.pyc in __init__(self, formdata, obj, prefix, **kwargs)
    222             of a matching keyword argument to the field, if one exists.
    223         """
--> 224         super(Form, self).__init__(self._unbound_fields, prefix=prefix)
    225 
    226         for name, field in iteritems(self._fields):

pathwtforms/form.pyc in __init__(self, fields, prefix)
     37 
     38         for name, unbound_field in fields:
---> 39             field = unbound_field.bind(form=self, name=name, prefix=prefix, translations=translations)
     40             self._fields[name] = field
     41 

path/wtforms/fields/core.pyc in bind(self, form, name, prefix, translations, **kwargs)
    299 
    300     def bind(self, form, name, prefix='', translations=None, **kwargs):
--> 301         return self.field_class(_form=form, _prefix=prefix, _name=name, _translations=translations, *self.args, **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs))
    302 
    303     def __repr__(self):

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_form'
```

I suppose the _form field isn't instantiated properly.
Any ideas how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: What you've posted simply can't work, and on top of that can't generate the error you stated (it won't get that far). For one thing, you're trying to instantiate `MyField` before you define it; if you fix that, you're passing a parameter to it but you haven't written it to accept any parameters. Both of these will cause errors other than the one you mention before you even get to calling the parent class. Please post code that *actually exhibits just the error you're asking about.*

Comment: the MyField class is defined in another file. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyField.__init__` method is missing the requisite keyword args.  Try this:

```
class MyField(TextField):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):  # You were missing the **kwargs
        super(MyField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

The `*` and `**` operators<sup>(?)</sup> in function calls do the following:

- If used in a function signature they specify that all remaining positional (`*`) or keyword (`**`) arguments should be placed in a `tuple` / `dict` (respectively) and the data should be bound to the name that follows the `*` / `**`.
- If used in a function *call* they specify that the `tuple` or `list` (for `*`) or `dict` (for `**`) should be unpacked and passed to the function as a list of arguments / key-word arguments.